# Need help in converting a loop into something that can be used in an php object

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This standalone code works perfectly

```
$pdf
->addPDF('../docx/tag_1.pdf', 'all')
->addPDF('../docx/tag_2.pdf', 'all')
->addPDF('../docx/tag_3.pdf', 'all')
->merge('file', 'merged.pdf');
```

What I need is the ability to be able to dynamically create a loop that adds tags from a variable that holds the number of tags created, for example:

```
$pdf
```

start loop

```
->addPDF("../docx/tag_{$count}.pdf", 'all')
->addPDF("../docx/tag_{$count}.pdf", 'all')
->addPDF("../docx/tag_{$count}.pdf, 'all')
```

etc. until the loop is finished

```
->merge('file', 'merged.pdf');
```

How can I achieve this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$number_of_tags = 7;

for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_tags; $i++)
{
    $pdf->addPDF('../docx/tag_'.$i.'.pdf', 'all');
}

$pdf->merge('file', 'merged.pdf');
```

Comment: thank you that has made progress as I now have a different error !

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $pdf->addPDF("../docx/tag_$i.pdf", 'all');
}
$pdf->merge('file', 'merged.pdf');
```

Comment: thank you that has made progress as I now have a different error !